# In Foreshortened Area - why we use cosine?

Tags: image-processing

When calculating Foreshortened Area as in the image below, why are we using cosine(theta) to calculate the scaled length in the x-axis? I understand intuitively why no correction is needed in the y-axis, but can't understand exactly why cosine for the x-axis

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the part where the projected rectangle has an extent in the $x$ direction equal to $A_x \cos \theta$?

Comment: No, this is basically what I'm trying to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I've annotated their picture in red.

Basically, whatever is happening on that bottom plane (labeled $x$), there's a corresponding image of it on the slanted plane (labeled $x \cos \theta$).  If something appears to be $x$ units long on the bottom plane, then -- just because of trigonometry -- it must be $x \cos \theta$ units long on the slanted plane.

Their example has the tilt only happening in the $x$ direction, so the $y$ direction isn't scaled.

Thus, the length $A_x$ in the bottom plane appears to be $A_x \cos \theta$ in the upper plane.  Because $A = A_x A_y$, $\left(A_x \cos \theta\right) A_y = A \cos \theta$.

[image]

If this still isn't working for you, then try drawing out some examples yourself.  Make a base line, and put some tick marks on it.  Then make a slanted line off of it.  Then draw in some really light-weight "connection lines", *at right angles to your slanted line*, from your slanted line to the tick marks.  See how they're forshortened.

Alternately, take something thin like a card, your cell phone, or a book and hold it at arms length.  Look at it face on -- that's $\theta = 0$.  Note how big it looks.  That's because $\cos 0 = 1$.  Now look at it edge-on -- that's $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Note that you can't see the face of it -- that's because $\cos \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$.  If you have brain cells that are still unconvinced, slowly rotate the thing from edge-on to face on, contemplating how it's looking bigger in one dimension, and how maybe that's proportional to $\cos \theta$.

Keep this up until (A) all objecting brain cells get exhausted and die, or (B) that degree in Business Administration starts looking attractive.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\theta$ is the angle between the normal vectors of the two planes, hence it is also the angle between the planes. That's how you obtain $A_x\cos\theta$ as the projection. The length $A_y$ remains unchanged because the direction of projection is perpendicular to that side of the rectangle.